# Taking limit at level of differential equation vs. solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following ODE

$$ y(x)=\lambda \  \frac{dy}{dx},$$

which has the solution $y(x)=c  \ e^{x/\lambda}.$

If I want to analyse now the behavior of the system for $\lambda  \to 0$, at what level do I do this? Because I seem to get different results. At the level of the ODE I get $y(x)=0$ and at the level of the solution $y(x)$ blows up.

Comment: The keywords you are looking for are: asymptotics, perturbation theory, and in this case, boundary layer theory (because the small parameter appears next to the highest derivative in the differential equation). The point $\lambda=0$ is a singular point of the DE: the solution has different character for small finite $\lambda$ versus $\lambda=0$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have some explicit references where this is discussed?

Comment: One good reference for Boundary Layer Theory that gives a similar example would be Chapter 2 of Viscous Flow by Ockendon and Ockendon. Specifically they analyze the equation: $\epsilon \frac{du}{dx}+u=x, \ \  u(0)=1 $. I think this can be found somewhere on the internet.

Comment: It's not incorrect that you would get different results because ultimately depending on at what level you take $\lambda\rightarrow0$, you're left with different problems. The key is to examine the errors being made in each case (when $\lambda<<1, \lambda\neq0$) and there magnitudes relative to said parameter.

Comment: @korni1990 Bender and Orszag: *Advanced mathematical methods* is very good